# avoid adding the same element if exist in the list instead just add the elements inside the existing list

Tags: java, java-8

Below is the sample code

```
                String jsonString = "{\n" +
                        "   \"models\":[\n" +
                        "      {\n" +
                        "         \"model\":{\n" +
                        "            \"code\":\"ALL\",\n" +
                        "            \"type\":null,\n" +
                        "            \"name\":\"ALL\",\n" +
                        "            \"feature_types\":null\n" +
                        "         }\n" +
                        "      },\n" +
                        "      {\n" +
                        "         \"model\":{\n" +
                        "            \"code\":\"102e\",\n" +
                        "            \"defaultLookup\":\"false\",\n" +
                        "            \"type\":\"SIT\",\n" +
                        "            \"name\":\"MUSTANG\",\n" +
                        "            \"feature_types\":[\n" +
                        "               {\n" +
                        "                  \"feature_type\":{\n" +
                        "                     \"code\":\"A\",\n" +
                        "                     \"desc\":\"All feature types\"\n" +
                        "                  }\n" +
                        "               },\n" +
                        "               {\n" +
                        "                  \"feature_type\":{\n" +
                        "                     \"code\":\"B\",\n" +
                        "                     \"desc\":\"Series\"\n" +
                        "                  }\n" +
                        "               },\n" +
                        "               {\n" +
                        "                  \"feature_type\":{\n" +
                        "                     \"code\":\"C\",\n" +
                        "                     \"desc\":\"BodyStyle\"\n" +
                        "                  }\n" +
                        "               }\n" +
                        "            ]\n" +
                        "         }\n" +
                        "      },\n" +
                        "      {\n" +
                        "         \"model\":{\n" +
                        "            \"code\":\"980p\",\n" +
                        "            \"defaultLookup\":\"false\",\n" +
                        "            \"type\":\"SIT\",\n" +
                        "            \"name\":\"Ranger\",\n" +
                        "            \"feature_types\":[\n" +
                        "               {\n" +
                        "                  \"feature_type\":{\n" +
                        "                     \"code\":\"C\",\n" +
                        "                     \"desc\":\"All feature types\"\n" +
                        "                  }\n" +
                        "               },\n" +
                        "               {\n" +
                        "                  \"feature_type\":{\n" +
                        "                     \"code\":\"D\",\n" +
                        "                     \"desc\":\"Series\"\n" +
                        "                  }\n" +
                        "               } \n" +
                        "            ]\n" +
                        "         }\n" +
                        "      },\n" +
                        "      {\n" +
                        "         \"model\":{\n" +
                        "            \"code\":\"kkpou\",\n" +
                        "            \"defaultLookup\":\"false\",\n" +
                        "            \"type\":\"UAT\",\n" +
                        "            \"name\":\"Transit Custom\",\n" +
                        "            \"feature_types\":[\n" +
                        "               {\n" +
                        "                  \"feature_type\":{\n" +
                        "                     \"code\":\"F\",\n" +
                        "                     \"desc\":\"All feature types\"\n" +
                        "                  }\n" +
                        "               },\n" +
                        "               {\n" +
                        "                  \"feature_type\":{\n" +
                        "                     \"code\":\"G\",\n" +
                        "                     \"desc\":\"Series\"\n" +
                        "                  }\n" +
                        "               },\n" +
                        "               {\n" +
                        "                  \"feature_type\":{\n" +
                        "                     \"code\":\"H\",\n" +
                        "                     \"desc\":\"Payload\"\n" +
                        "                  }\n" +
                        "               }\n" +
                        "            ]\n" +
                        "         }\n" +
                        "      }\n" +
                        "   ]\n" +
                        "}";
    
    for(int i = 0; i<myData.size();i++)
        {
            String type = "SIT";
            FeaturedItems item = resultList.stream().filter(featureItem -> type != null && type.equals(featureItem.getType())).findFirst().orElse(null);
            if (type != null) {
                item = FeaturedItems.builder().type(type).items(new ArrayList<>()).build();
                resultList.add(item);//if the item already exists in the list don't add the new item, instead just add the elements in the exisiting item.
 //tried the below commented code to add the item if it doesn't contain in the list -- start
                  /*boolean flagFound = false;
                    for (FeaturedItems featureItem : resultList) {
                        if (featureItem.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                            flagFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                  if(!flagFound) resultList.add(item);*/
 //tried the above commented code to add the item if it doesn't contain in the list -- End
                for (int count = 0; count < features.size(); count++) {
                    String id = getFid(count);
                    MyDataBuild build = ....//logic to set values in the properties
                    item.getItems().add(build);
                }
            }    
        }
      lookUpData.setFeatureGroups(resultList);
    }   
    }
```

If the **type** value is already defined in the defined **featureItems**, then instead of creating the new object in the featureItems list, i need to add the **unique** items(desc,id) to the existing items element for the matching ***type***. The code snippet mentioned above doesn't add the elements to the existing items if the type is matching in the featureItems list, instead it is creating the new element as shown in the output json sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Map` instead will make your live much easier. However your example is missing some data so it's a bit hard to understand what is actually happening in your code. So I can give you only a simple example for the usage.

```
Map<String, FeaturedItems> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
// Get the FeaturedItems for the given type. If none is present create a new one.
FeaturedItems items = resultMap.computeIfAbsent(type, k -> FeaturedItems.builder().type(k).items(new ArrayList<>()).build());
// Add your item to the list
Sale newItem // Obtain new item
items.getItems().add(newItem);
```